# A centered plus-minus symbol

Tags: symbols

I'm using the `amsbook` document class with the `psamsfonts` and `mathpazo` packages. The minus sign touches the bottom of the text line. Is there a way to slightly miniaturize and vertically center the `\pm` symbol with the number?

```
\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsbook}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
$\pm 1$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For simple uses

```
\newcommand{\rpm}{\raisebox{.2ex}{$\scriptstyle\pm$}}
```

should do. If you need a *very* accurate measuring

```
\newcommand{\rpm}{\sbox0{$1$}\sbox2{$\scriptstyle\pm$}
  \raise\dimexpr(\ht0-\ht2)/2\relax\box2 }
```

If you need the symbol also in subscripts or superscripts, something else is needed.

The `psamsfonts` option is obsolete, as far as I remember.

Comment: Thank you! Is psamsfonts superseded by any package?

Comment: No, the PostScript fonts are used automatically and the option does nothing, apart issuing a warning.