# Creating a \precneq symbol

Tags: symbols, amsmath

Going through the comprehensive symbols list, and also Detexify, we see that through various packages (mostly `amssymb`) we can get the symbols

- `\prec` Precedes. Unicode U+227A: ≺
- `\preceq` Precedes or equals to. Unicode U+227C: ≼
- `\precsim` Precedes or equivalent to. Unicode U+227E: ≾
- `\precnsim` Precedes and not equivalent to. <strike>(I don't think there is a unicode symbol for this one)</strike> *Edit*: as [David Carlisle points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58887/119) I just didn't scroll down far enough. It is Unicode U+22E8.

Its cousin `<` supports variants `\leq` and `\lneq`. Evidently, however, there is no `\precneq` equivalent for the "precedes" symbol.

*Question*: Has someone already constructed the symbol and placed it in a package? If not, how can I construct such a symbol? It should start from the AMS `\preceq` symbol and drop a cancelling sign over the equals-to part *only*.

*Edit*: for clarification, something like the following is what I desire:

[image]

Comment: In the `amssymb` package there is a `\npreceq` symbol.

Comment: Arguably one should only use `\prec` to mean precedes and not equals to and `\preceq` for the possibility of equals to. In which case the symbol would not be necessary. But sometimes in the text it is nice to emphasize the fact that A precedes B and _not_ equals to B.

Comment: @CountZero: `\npreceq` cancels the whole symbol. I just want the canceling line to drop over the equals part similar to `\precnsim` or to `\lneq` (also from amssymb).

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer what you exactly need. Hope that's ok with you.

Comment: i've discovered that a large number of math symbols that should be included in the unicode name index, aren't.  i've reported this to the unicode editor.  i think this symbol is *not* in unicode yet; if someone can find a published instance, please let me know, and i'll submit it for unicode consideration.  (details for contacting me are in my profile.)

Comment: well, i lied in my previous comment.  this symbol *is* in unicode, at Ux2AB1, and thus should be in the stix fonts.  those aren't really well documented yet, but a comment by khaled hosny on april 5, regarding [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50792/a-better-pm-symbol), states that "TeX support for STIX fonts is well under way, stay tuned ;)"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lost symbol sighted in `mathabx`. :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$\precneq$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: A nice resource in such cases, the [Comprehensive Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive). I admit, at times it can be quite tedious browsing it for a given symbol... but so far it's the best thing I know of.

Comment: With a pointer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) if one doesn't want to load the whole `mathabx` (which changes many symbols). This symbol is in slot `"AC` of `mathb`.

Comment: Hah, I did check the CSL, but I missed the `mathabx` section for _negated_ binary relations. Thanks!

Comment: @WillieWong: Can happen to anyone. `;)`

Answer (score 5):

U+22E8 is PRECEDES BUT NOT EQUIVALENT TO

Although the reference glyph has a negated wavy line rather than a negated straight line

see http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007doc/022.html

Other information about that character from the source of that document:

```xml
  <character id="U022E8" dec="8936" mode="math" type="relation">
     <unicodedata category="Sm" combclass="0" bidi="ON" mirror="Y" mathclass="R"/>
     <afii>21B1</afii>
     <latex>\precedesnotsimilar </latex>
     <Elsevier grid="blr" ent="prnsim">
        <desc>precedes, not similar</desc>
     </Elsevier>
     <AMS>\precnsim</AMS>
     <APS>prnsim</APS>
     <Wolfram>NotPrecedesTilde</Wolfram>
     <entity id="prnsim" set="8879-isoamsn">
        <desc>/precnsim N: precedes, not similar</desc>
     </entity>
     <entity id="prnsim" set="9573-1991-isoamsn">
        <desc>/precnsim N: precedes, not similar</desc>
     </entity>
     <entity id="prnsim" set="9573-2003-isoamsn">
        <desc>/precnsim N: precedes, not similar</desc>
     </entity>
     <entity id="precnsim" set="mmlalias">
        <desc>alias ISOAMSN prnsim</desc>
     </entity>
     <font name="hlcra" pos="235"/>
     <operator-dictionary form="infix" lspace="5" rspace="5" priority="265"/>
     <description unicode="1.1">PRECEDES BUT NOT EQUIVALENT TO</description>
  </character>
```

Comment: Thanks! You tracked down the unicode character for `\precnsim` (I edited the question to reflect that find). But that is not quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here the [unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2ab1/index.htm) solution with use of [fontspec](/questions/tagged/fontspec) and the [font you like](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2ab1/fontsupport.htm):

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{{\fontspec{#1}\symbol{"2AB1}}}
\textwidth=6.5cm

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{U+2AB1 -- PRECEDES ABOVE SINGLE-LINE NOT EQUAL TO}
\begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
    Font & Symbol\\\midrule
    Code2000 & \test{code2000.ttf}\\
    Quivira & \test{quivira.otf}\\
    STIX Math & \test{STIX Math}\\
    Symbola & \test{symbola.ttf}\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And here are two more fonts with help of the package [unicode-math](/questions/tagged/unicode-math):

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document} 
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
$A\precneq B\succneq C$

%\setmathfont{Cambria Math} % not available on my system
%$A\precneq B\succneq C$

\setmathfont{Asana Math}
$A\precneq B\succneq C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The symbol  \test{symbola.ttf} you show is precisely what I want. However it is very unclear to me how I can access it. Is part of a font in a package?

Comment: No, you will need the font installed on your system. Free to download. And then run the part wit Xe- or LuaLaTeX