# Identify and import a "curly precneq" from a package

Tags: symbols, import

I would like to use the following symbol (from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229882/67730), see the "Symbola" in the picture):
[image]

Ideally, I would like to have a command which make it appear without loading a package which may change the fonts in my text.
It is however very unclear to me how to adapt this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14388/67730) in order to do so. 
Actually, I can't even find a package where the above pictured symbol is contained. Detexify doesn't help me.

Comment: Try `texdoc symobols-a4`. There are several `\precneq` symbols in different fonts. I would just load a package as in most cases then disruption to existing fonts is minimal.

Comment: Which answer are you referring to? The link points to one that doesn't feature that symbol.

Comment: @egreg sorry, I got confused with the links, let me edit the question.

Comment: @Surb Below the answer you'd like to link to there is a “share” link: click on it and copy the URL, then paste it here.

Comment: @egreg done :)..

Comment: Are you using `pdflatex` or XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX? If the former, then the answer you refer to cannot help. Unless you'd like to use the STIX symbol.

Comment: @egreg "Are you using `pdflatex` or XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX? " Honestly, I don't know and I don't know how to check that. I use Texstudio with the default compilation setting (double green arrow)

Comment: @egreg It seems to be pdflatex if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: @Surb Then it's most likely `pdflatex`. Symbola is out of the question, unless you make a PDF with the symbol and use it as a graphic inclusion.

Comment: @egreg ah... and I guess that this graphic inclusion will be complicated and dramatically slow down the compilation..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Symbola font (it's free) and place it in a working directory.

Prepare the following document and call it `precneq.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Symbola}[Path=./,Extension=.ttf]

\begin{document}
\symbol{"2AB1}
\end{document}
```

Compile it with XeLaTeX to obtain `precneq.pdf`.

Now copy this PDF file in the same directory as your main document. The code for using it is between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (included) in the following test file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\precneq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\use@precneq\relax}}
\newcommand\use@precneq{%
  \text{%
    \raisebox{-0.5ex}{%
      \scalebox{\f@size}{%
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{precneq}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\precneq b$ $a\preceq b$ $x_{\precneq}y_{\preceq}$

\medskip

{\Large $a\precneq b$ $a\preceq b$ $x_{\precneq}y_{\preceq}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it worth the pain? I'd simply import all the “prec” symbols from `mathabx`.

Comment: Sorry, it is late here and so I will try your solution tomorrow. Your pictures look great and exactly what I want. As it it for my thesis, I think it is worth the pain. If this slows down the compilation I'll just make the change for the last compilation. Thanks already for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{ <-6> mathb5 <6-7> mathb6 <7-8>
mathb7 <8-9> mathb8 <9-10> mathb9 <10-12> mathb10 <12-> mathb12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\precneq}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"AC}


\begin{document}

\[ a \precneq b\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not the symbol I want. The "\prec" has a different shape in your answer. I managed to import \precneq but again, the output is not the one desired.

Comment: I borrowed it from `mathabx`. Where did you find your symbol? The answer you linked to also uses mathabx.

Comment: This is the point. I found it in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229882/67730) (Symbola version) but it is unclear to me how it is related to any package

Comment: I don't think it's related to a package, since the answer uses `fontspec` (hence it works with `lualatex` or `xelatex`).

Comment: Indeed, it seems that there is no "simple" solution to my problem..

Comment: Maybe I should just import \prec and \preceq from mathbx so they all look the same.

Comment: May be indeed. It's not so curly, but it's not too far. The documentation  provides the hexadecimal code of the symbols, so it's easy to do.