# \mediumvee and \mediumwedge?

Tags: symbols

[image]I would like to have access to a disjunction sign (and a conjunction sign), larger than $\vee$ and smaller than $\bigvee$ ($\wedge$ and $\bigwedge); its height should be the same as $\exists$ and $\forall$.

The British logician Geoffrey Hunter used such a $\mediumvee$ and $\mediumwedge$, in his book *Metalogic: An Introduction to the Metatheory of Standard First Order Logic*, for the existential and universal quantifiers. Sometimes one sees the use of much larger versions for the mentioned purpose, but I prefer the size I indicated.

How may the problem be resolved?

Comment: Here's a start: [How to "center" a math operator defined by re-scaling a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/391761/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd find it utterly confusing if the “Hunter-style” universal quantifier is used along the standard “and” symbol.

Here is a possibility, scaling `\land` to match the uppercase letters (I used T as the matching character).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hunterforall}{%
  % no need to make it scalable in sub/superscripts
  \mathord{\resizebox{!}{\fontcharht\textfont1 `T}{\raisebox{\depth}{$\land$}}}%
}
\RenewCommandCopy{\forall}{\hunterforall}

\begin{document}

$\forall x(F^*(x)\land F^{*\prime}(x))$

\end{document}
```

[image]